How can I create a dynamic report where the columns fit the page width?
How can I make the columns in this dynamic report in JasperReports, which are already placed horizontally, adjust to the page width, regardless of how many columns are sent, since the exact number is not known in advance? The idea is for it to be dynamic, with the columns sent from the front end to generate the report.
It is important to note that JasperReports does not allow expressions in column widths, and splitting the information into a single column using '|' is not a viable option, as too much information becomes disorganized.
This is the source of my report:
<jasperReport name="DynamicHorizontalReport" language="java" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b0727a37-1a05-4de8-b9d4-5b885bb087be">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <dataset name="ColumnDataset" uuid="08e121b4-15af-40d4-9d5e-ccf38798375d">
        <parameter name="DATA_ROWS" class="java.util.List"/>
        <query language="sql"><![CDATA[]]></query>
        <field name="columnName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </dataset>
    <dataset name="RowDataset" uuid="ea5a841b-77a6-4484-be9e-4d574850d546">
        <parameter name="DATA_ROWS" class="java.util.List"/>
        <query language="sql"><![CDATA[]]></query>
        <field name="columnName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </dataset>
    <parameter name="nameUserGeneratedReport" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="COLUMN_NAMES" class="java.util.List"/>
    <parameter name="DATA_ROWS" class="java.util.List"/>
    <parameter name="COLUMN_COUNT" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <title height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <element kind="rectangle" uuid="f8c917d8-22b6-4b62-b4f8-142ce77bfbf9" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="79" backcolor="#3366CC"/>
        <element kind="textField" uuid="9a8dc715-de2e-4266-a780-f9e895091aef" x="0" y="10" width="802" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontSize="16.0" bold="true" hTextAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle">
            <expression><![CDATA["REPORTE DINÁMICO"]]></expression>
        </element>
        <element kind="textField" uuid="d93b8602-7285-43c6-97f7-67d791234c83" x="0" y="40" width="802" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontSize="12.0" hTextAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle">
            <expression><![CDATA["Generado por: " + $P{nameUserGeneratedReport}]]></expression>
        </element>
    </title>
    <columnHeader height="30" splitType="Stretch">
        <element kind="component" uuid="aa8f6e0c-955f-47f2-b6a5-3bfbf8583eef" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="30">
            <component kind="list" printOrder="Horizontal">
                <datasetRun uuid="ffb7e621-33df-4db2-bcf6-e2c70279ab06" subDataset="ColumnDataset">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{COLUMN_NAMES})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <contents height="30" width="802">
                    <element kind="textField" uuid="3aada7bd-2029-4d96-a625-a7af54ba335e" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="30" bold="true" hTextAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle" style="Table_TH">
                        <expression><![CDATA[$F{columnName}]]></expression>
                    </element>
                </contents>
            </component>
        </element>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <element kind="component" uuid="2def4882-95fb-4483-89cd-40820434181c" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="30">
                <component kind="list" printOrder="Horizontal">
                    <datasetRun uuid="fa8885fc-cc7f-4518-8996-eeac3e707e39" subDataset="RowDataset">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{COLUMN_NAMES})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <contents height="30" width="802">
                        <element kind="textField" uuid="a3b88170-9543-475b-bcd9-3e6b587dbf6f" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="30" textAdjust="StretchHeight" hTextAlign="Center" vTextAlign="Middle" style="Table_TD">
                            <expression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} <= $P{DATA_ROWS}.size() ? ((java.util.Map)$P{DATA_ROWS}.get($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1)).get($F{columnName}) : ""]]></expression>
                        </element>
                    </contents>
                </component>
            </element>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>

This is the basic service I have in Spring Boot:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/generate-dynamic-pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> generateDynamicPdfReport8(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestData) {
        try {
            List<Map<String, Object>> data = (List<Map<String, Object>>) requestData.get("data");
            String nameUserGeneratedReport = (String) requestData.get("username");
    
            if (data == null || data.isEmpty()) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("No data provided");
            }
    
            Map<String, Object> firstRecord = data.get(0);
            if (firstRecord.size() > 12) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Maximum of 12 columns allowed");
            }
    
            // Obtener los nombres de las columnas
            List<Map<String, String>> columnNames = firstRecord.keySet().stream()
                .map(key -> {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("columnName", key);
                    return map;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
            // Preparar los parámetros del reporte
            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("COLUMN_NAMES", columnNames);
            parameters.put("DATA_ROWS", data);
            parameters.put("nameUserGeneratedReport", nameUserGeneratedReport);
            parameters.put("COLUMN_COUNT", columnNames.size());
            parameters.put("REPORT_ORIENTATION", "Landscape");
    
            // Cargar y compilar el reporte
            ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("reports/ReportDynamicTable4.jasper");
            InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inputStream);
    
            // Generar el reporte
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
    
            // Exportar a PDF
            byte[] pdfBytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData("filename", "dynamic_horizontal_report.pdf");
    
            return new ResponseEntity<>(pdfBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error generating report: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

I tried to calculate the column widths so that they would adjust dynamically to the page width, but I couldn't achieve it. I attempted to do it with a subreport, but I was unable to make it work
